# Java .mp4 stream corruption at the end of a video - network error

Tags: java, streaming, mp4

Please help, My problem is to stream bytes from .mp4 with code on this page http://balusc.blogspot.ru/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html and it is almost done properly, but the stream is always corrupted at the end of a movie ex.:

video is 57mins long - on 52 second fail occurred with message: "A network error cause the stream fail part way.", I've tried to test it several times, thought that it was really network problem - but it always the same. I presume there could be some specific issue with code with .mp4 to represent bytes for browser.

Any help would be appreciated.

The error msg in Browser: **A network error caused the video download to fail part-way.**

The problem should be in this part of code, now I suppose that the system Linux Ubuntu, may be JVM is not enough space with file size over 1.6Gb as  **C. Trimble** mentioned in comments - probably I should allocate more memory on read stream socket for files or in JVM itself I don't know how (-Xms, -Xmx):

```
  private static void copy(RandomAccessFile input, OutputStream output, long start, long length) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int read;

    try {
      if (input.length() == length) {
        // Write full range.
        Logger.log("length==length read/write "+length);
        while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
          output.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
      } else {
        // Write partial range.
        input.seek(start);
        Logger.log("start length: "+start);
        long toRead = length+start;

        while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
          if ((toRead -= read) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, read);
            Logger.log("toRead -= read read/write "+toRead);
//            output.write(buffer, 0, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

          } else { // the end of a movie - ERROR APPEARS HERE !!!
            Logger.log("the end read/write "+toRead);
            output.write(buffer, 0, (int) toRead + read);
//            output.write(buffer, 0, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.log(Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()), "error.log");
      Logger.log(ex.getMessage(), "error.log");
    }
  }
```

Response Content-Range from logs started from 1-st to the end when it falls:

2014-12-27 17:55:625 Content-Range: bytes 1784938496-1787737811/1787737812
2014-12-27 17:55:645 Content-Range: bytes 262144-1787737811/1787737812
2014-12-27 17:55:795 Content-Range: bytes 1048576-1787737811/1787737812
2014-12-27 17:55:190 Content-Range: bytes 1572864-1787737811/1787737812
2014-12-27 17:55:676 Content-Range: bytes 2097152-1787737811/1787737812
2014-12-27 17:55:195 Content-Range: bytes 2621440-1787737811/1787737812
2014-12-27 17:55:721 Content-Range: bytes 3145728-1787737811/1787737812
2014-12-27 17:55:421 Content-Range: bytes 786432-1787737811/1787737812
2014-12-27 17:55:992 Content-Range: bytes 1409024-1787737811/1787737812
2014-12-27 17:55:453 Content-Range: bytes 1835008-1787737811/1787737812
2014-12-27 17:55:34 Content-Range: bytes 2359296-1787737811/1787737812
2014-12-27 17:55:757 Content-Range: bytes 2883584-1787737811/1787737812
2014-12-27 17:55:340 Content-Range: bytes 5767168-1787737811/1787737812

All headers from FireBug Net tool - response:

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Disposition inline;filename="True.Detective.S01E02.BDRip.720p.mp4"
Content-Length  1769137613
Content-Range   bytes 1572864-1770710476/1770710477
Content-Type    video/mp4
Date    Sat, 27 Dec 2014 17:53:54 GMT
Etag    True.Detective.S01E02.BDRip.720p.mp4_1770710477_1419450095000
Expires Sat, 03 Jan 2015 17:53:54 GMT
Last-Modified   Wed, 24 Dec 2014 19:41:35 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Request headers:

```
Accept  video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  _ga=GA1.2.1399057170.1418569894; ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22013f5e68900cbd78accb95573968b6f3%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22109.173.78.7%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A72%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.3%3B+WOW64%3B+rv%3A34.0%29+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F34.0%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1419680981%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7D4785741ee92c92e18475135f708e4283; PHPSESSID=s0cbpcnbqegb5u3312joe36510; _gat=1; _ym_visorc_27490695=w
Host    test.fast-seasons.ru:8080
Range   bytes=1572864-
Referer http://test.fast-seasons.ru:8080/tv/streaming?token=549ef20cd8a82
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
```

output in logs before fail - seems to be good before system/JVM fail because of bigger file or memory allocation:

```
2014-12-27 23:44:783 toRead -= read read/write 5792296
2014-12-27 23:44:783 toRead -= read read/write 5783080
2014-12-27 23:44:783 toRead -= read read/write 5773864
2014-12-27 23:44:783 toRead -= read read/write 5767168
```

Sometimes, in custom logs, I see the following exception:

```
2014-12-28 13:47:522 [org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:413), org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk
.java:342), org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:438), org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:
426), org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91), ru.fastseasons.streaming.StreamServlet.copy(StreamServlet.java:446)
, ru.fastseasons.streaming.StreamServlet.processRequest(StreamServlet.java:329), ru.fastseasons.streaming.StreamServlet.doGet(StreamServlet.java:100), javax.
servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620), javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFil
terChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208), org.ap
ache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java
:122), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170), org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.jav
a:98), org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.jav
a:116), org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408), org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11P
rocessor.java:1040), org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607), org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$
SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolEx
ecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]
2014-12-28 13:47:522 null
```

Sure I looked at line 446 and saw the read variable passed as 3d argument to read number of bytes containing in it, but there shouldn't be program problems with this, because read var is always >0 through while loop condition.

The strange behaviour as I suppose is that it happens with files of .mp4 format larger 1Gb, may be this is Linux or JVM memory suffocation - I don't know and I don't know how to test it.
Also I've tried to look at ulimit -r -l

```
real-time priority              (-r) 95
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
```

There are actually 3 rows in logs for every mp4/video stream (when the video plays through browser Chrome on Windows) - seems to be quite normal, here it is:

```
2014-12-28 22:29:167 Content-Range: bytes 0-1180454117/1180454118
2014-12-28 22:29:168 Content-Length: 1180454118
2014-12-28 22:29:601 Content-Range: bytes 1178816938-1180454117/1180454118
2014-12-28 22:29:601 Content-Length: 1637180
2014-12-28 22:29:768 Content-Range: bytes 1178816986-1180454117/1180454118
2014-12-28 22:29:769 Content-Length: 1180454070
```

Works in Chrome, thx to EJP, but still problems in FF.

Edits implemented in code after @EJP correction:

```
long toRead = length;

while (toRead > 0 && (read = input.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, toRead))) > 0)
{
    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
    toRead -= read;
}
```

Comment: It is also gziped like it should, so the code totally adequate, this little issue is disappointing though.

Comment: Can you log the request and response headers that are created during playback and post them?

Comment: What does the file system say the size of this file is?  From the headers, it seems to be about 1.7GB.  Curious if you are running into some kind of file size related issue.

Comment: Thx Trimble, that should be the issue. I don't know where to look at and how to extend/allocate more memory or socket read option for bigger files to IO.

Comment: You could try using a Channel to get the size (long shot, but might work) or try returning `*` for the total size in the `Content-Range` header.

Comment: This is a guess, but the line `long length = file.length();` is probably the problem.  There could be a system call there that is passing an int.

Comment: What Java version are you running?  `file.length()` is working correctly for me with Java 7 and 8.

Comment: I'm working with Java 7 and I don't think the problem is in `file.length()`, though thx anyway.

Comment: In logs, no exception whatsoever ?

Comment: Exceptions in logs and assumptions edited in post.

Comment: Try to modify `catalina.sh` and add in `CATALINA_OPTS` `-Xmx2048m`

Comment: I'm restarting Tomcat with service tomcat7 restart, find command couldn't find any catalina.sh, I did not created catalina.sh myself.

Comment: `sudo find / -name "catalina.sh"` ?

Comment: Nope, it is here `nano /etc/default/tomcat7` I've set `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms10000m -Xmx20000m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -verbose"` - we'll see if it helps - then ToYonos will take his pie =)

Comment: Finger crossed. However, setting Xms ( initial memory allocation) to almost 10 GB is a little big don't you thing ? Unless your server is well equipped...

Comment: My server is equipped with 32Gb RAM )

Comment: Unfortunately this is not JVM memory allocation issue, ahh hope someone can help me with this exhausting situation. I think this is rather Content-Ranges - see last rows edited in post.

Comment: `Logger.log("the end read/write "+toRead);` never happens, whatever the browser ?

Comment: Yes, it is never happens - there are always +n bytes to read I think.

Comment: You used @EJP optimisation or just the `long toRead = length;` fix ? Beside, could you give me an exemple of `length` passed to the `copy` method ?

Answer (score 1):

```
long toRead = length+start;
```

The problem is here. It should be:

```
long toRead = length;
```

However your code can be simplified considerably:

```
while (toRead > 0 && (read = input.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, toRead))) > 0)
{
    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
    toRead -= read;
}
```

E&OE

Comment: Ok, but what is count - is that should be read? Also, honestly I've changed `long toRead = length;` to `long toRead = length+start;` experimenting, sorry for that, but this shouldn't be work around at all. I will edit code with Your considerations and will soon respond. Thx for help.

Comment: Now it is ok with Chrome, but not with FF. Nevertheless - point up, thx for help. May be U have other thoughts about it?

Comment: I will check Your answer as accepted if no other will take the plunge - it is Yours.

Comment: It seems, though that everything works fine now, this solution is simple and trivial, but the main thing - it works, I`ll give all I can =)

Comment: @zeusakm Thanks. I fixed the `count`/`read` problem. It doesn't matter what the browser is.

Comment: Sure, for streaming bytes IO it doesn't (no matter what browser to use), but there was glitches in FF, so I thought may be this could happen because of Content-Ranges.

Comment: Actually there is still problem with FF, sorry, You can try it Your-self. It is always interrupted at the end of a movie, especially if video > 40 mins long. http://fast-seasons.ru

Comment: There may well be a problem with FF, but it isn't due to this code.

Comment: I am answering your question here about the code you posted here. There is no Content-range header setting in your code. If you have another problem concerning other code, I suggest you post it somewhere where it will attract attention and maybe answers. Not in an obscure comment to an existing answer to something else.